# C# tooltip not showing even if set at form load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tooltip

Im having problem with setting my tooltip that will change depending on the button that is targetting on.

This is my form load event to set my tooltip.

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabView.TabPages.Clear();
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnACust, "Add customer");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRCust, "Remove customer");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSrch, "Search for an item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnEdit, "Edit selected item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnDel, "Delete selected item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSell, "Add item to cart");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnReg, "Sell item/s");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnCRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUpd, "Update item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUndo, "Reset to default values");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnECan, "Cancel all changes and close");
        dataGridSales.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
        dataGridSales.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("C2");
        dataGridSales.Columns[3].ValueType = typeof(Double);
        dataGridSales.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        lblTimeDate.Text = "Date: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        dateTimeToday.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
```

I even tried placing it here.

```
public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnACust, "Add customer");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRCust, "Remove customer");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSrch, "Search for an item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnEdit, "Edit selected item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnDel, "Delete selected item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSell, "Add item to cart");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnReg, "Sell item/s");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnCRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUpd, "Update item");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUndo, "Reset to default values");
        toolTip.SetToolTip(btnECan, "Cancel all changes and close");
    }
```

But the tooltip doesn't show anything. It will only show if I open my first tab page. If I choose to open other tab pages, it will not show.

This is the event where my first tab page will open

```
private void productsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!splitContainer1.Panel1.Contains(tabProd))
        {
            tabView.Visible = true;
            tabView.TabPages.Add(tabProd);
            tabView.SelectTab(tabProd);
            refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            tabView.SelectedTab = tabProd;
        }
    }
```

All my tabs are open the same way. I'm thinking of `MouseHover Event` but I have too many buttons, these are only some of it.

That button is located at my splitcontainer panel 2. Tab pages are open at splitcontainer panel 1.
[This is the sample of my form load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcJ18.jpg)

The user needs to open this tab page so that the tooltip will show. But I need the tooltip to show even if this tab is not open first.

[When my first tab page is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spvHi.jpg)

[Since first tab page is open, the tooltip is now showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVxqB.jpg)

Also tooltip doesn't show if other tab page is open.

[If the user open other tab page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpffm.jpg)

[If the user open other tab page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS4tt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set toolTip.ShowAlways to true.

so your code should look like this:

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabView.TabPages.Clear();
    toolTip.ShowAlways = true;
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnACust, "Add customer");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRCust, "Remove customer");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSrch, "Search for an item");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnEdit, "Edit selected item");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnDel, "Delete selected item");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnSell, "Add item to cart");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnReg, "Sell item/s");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnCRef, "Refresh search criteria and data");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUpd, "Update item");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnUndo, "Reset to default values");
    toolTip.SetToolTip(btnECan, "Cancel all changes and close");
    dataGridSales.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
    dataGridSales.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("C2");
    dataGridSales.Columns[3].ValueType = typeof(Double);
    dataGridSales.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    lblTimeDate.Text = "Date: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    dateTimeToday.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I have added the `ShowAlways` but still the same. Tooltip still not showing if my first tab page isnt open.

Comment: are the buttons added at design time? or are they added at runtime? if they are added at design time then they are a child control of the tabpage they are in. Maybe the tooltip class cant find the buttons in the other tabpages.

Comment: what do you mean design time? i have a splitcontainer. 1 container have my tab pages while some buttons are on the other container. so i dont think they are child control for the tab page. do you want to see my form?

Comment: i have edited my post, there are screenshot of my application.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer. design time is when you drag the components in the designer. and runtime is when the components are created during execution of the code.

Comment: they are added in design time. and im sure they are not child of the tabpage. even if i delete the buttons and tooltip. still same problem.